# How to find the row value of the cell clicked in a DataGrid on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, cell

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zllpr.png]

I wish to click on the end row of this data grid (in the above picture). When clicking this, I want to be able to find which row was clicked and pass the row-number over to another form.

Here are a few attempts that I have tried:

```
  private void CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int cell = dgFake.Items.IndexOf(((DataRowView)dgFake.Items[5]).Row);

        xamlAllocteAudits window = new xamlAllocteAudits
        {
            DataContext = cell
        };
        window.Show();
```

This attempt stayed as a value of '-1' no matter where I clicked in the column.

```
private void CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int cell = dgFake.Items.IndexOf(dgFake.SelectedIndex);

        xamlAllocteAudits window = new xamlAllocteAudits
        {
            DataContext = cell
        };
        window.Show();
```

This attempt displayed a different number starting at '-1' and incremented every time I clicked a cell in the column, but even if I click the bottom cell, the first click would always be '-1', so I assume this was not the row number value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SelectionChanged` event to do that:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (var row in dataGrid.SelectedItems) 
    {
        int index = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(row);
    }
}
```

If you are using single row selection, then you can just do this:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
}
```

If you just want cell data, then you can do this:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in dataGrid.SelectedCells) 
    {
        // do something with cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a handler in XAML which is set to my method CellClicked. When i move my code to the Selectionchanged it never hits that method? Maybe because im not changing the selection?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question is been answered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cdf2968-00e8-4ea5-aea0-ffd0e8230110/wpf-datagrid-current-row-index?forum=wpf) have a look.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i tried this and it comes up -1 again.

Answer (score -1):

Ben look at [code](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html) which tells you mechanism to detect the column, cell and row that has been clicked, by simple technique of navigation to parents.

Comment: referenced link is no longer available